# How make the gauge follow download function in Thread in wxPython?

Tags: python, download, youtube, wxwidgets, gauge

I am made YouTube downloader but the gauge progress not follow the function to download this video
i want the gauge start with video download starting and when the download finish the gauge finish

```
import wx
from pytube import YouTube
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread


class Tube(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Tube, self, *args, **kwargs).__init__(parent=None,id=wx.ID_ANY, title="New Frame", size=(600, 400))
    self.Centre()
    self.panel = wx.Panel(self, id=wx.ID_ANY, name="New Panel")
    self.textLink = wx.StaticText(parent=self.panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Edit YouTube URL", pos=(100, 50))
    self.editLink = wx.TextCtrl(parent=self.panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, size=(200, 25), pos=(250,50))
    self.downloadButton = wx.Button(parent=self.panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Download Video", pos=(250, 100))
    self.downloadButton.Bind(event=wx.EVT_BUTTON, handler=self.thread, source=self.downloadButton)
    self.progress = wx.Gauge(parent=self.panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, range=100,size=(200,25), pos=(200, 200))
    self.Show()

  def progressBar(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for value in range(101):
      wx.CallAfter(self.progress.SetValue, value)
      sleep(0.2)

  def Download(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.video = YouTube(self.editLink.GetValue())
    self.stream = self.video.streams.get_lowest_resolution()
    self.stream.download()

  def thread(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.threads = []
    self.thread1 = Thread(target=self.Download)
    self.thread2 = Thread(target=self.progressBar)
    self.threads.append(self.thread1)
    self.threads.append(self.thread2)
    for thread in self.threads:
      thread.setDaemon(True)
      thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = wx.App()
  screen = Tube()
  app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This question has been asked elsewhere, these links may help you  
 https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=35816  
 https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=11626

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use wxProgressDialog?

Check dialogs sample for details...

Thank you.

Comment: Dear Igor
The problem is not in the Progress bar type, the problem is that the progress bar does not follow the download function. I want the progress bar starts with the starting download and ends with the download end.
I want to move the progress bar according to the download function by threading

Comment: @thomas, this is exactly what wxProgressDialog does. Did you try it? What was the problem? It didn't end properly? It didn't move with the download?

Comment: Can you help me, I'm beginner in programming, i searched a lot, you can change me what it takes from the code and make sure it is well operate
Because the problem is linked to the progress bar with the function by threads
This simple application download video from YouTube